# Sharing a URL with image preview data sharesheet

Tags: android, android-intent

To try to share data from our app using the native Android sharesheet, we have been following this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Which gives us the following example:

[image: Description from Google documentation]

We have since been defining our own version of this sharing, which looks something like this on stock Android:

[image]

However, we seem to be unsuccessful so far in making Android show the sharesheet correctly. We have tried the following code, and I have attached the resulting screenshot for each code block so that you can compare to requirement:

```
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

if (event != null && event.getTitle() != null && collection.getTitle() != null) {
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, event.getTitle() + " - " + collection.getTitle());
}

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, collection.getShareUrl());

File thumbFile = DCPhotoUtils.captureView(rootView, R.id.shareThumbnailLayout);
Uri uriToImage = DCPhotoUtils.getUri(getContext(), thumbFile);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
sendIntent.setDataAndType(uriToImage, "image/*");
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));
```

Which results in just an imagine being shown:

[image]

We then tried the following approach:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
if (event != null && event.getTitle() != null && collection.getTitle() != null) {
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, event.getTitle() + " - " + collection.getTitle());
}

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, collection.getShareUrl());

File thumbFile = DCPhotoUtils.captureView(rootView, R.id.shareThumbnailLayout);
Uri uriToImage = DCPhotoUtils.getUri(getContext(), thumbFile);
sendIntent.setData(uriToImage);
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));
```

Which then results in... showing nothing haha:

[image]

And then finally we tried our third and last approach:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
if (event != null && event.getTitle() != null && collection.getTitle() != null) {
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, event.getTitle() + " - " + collection.getTitle());
}

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, collection.getShareUrl());

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));
```

Which does at least get us the link, but no link preview thumbnail:

[image]

So we are wondering what we are doing wrong that we cannot get the "full" intended result as shown in Google's documentation?

Comment: Could you please write an answer as well? Because the accepted answer seems incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had work a lot on this issue. Finally, I did it. You should try your third solution and add this command `shareIntent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", yourImageUri));`
It works perfectly with me

Comment: Thanks! This actually fixed it! Problem solved ✔

Comment: so this works for the thumbnail but actually attaching the image in the message seems like it needs to be shared via `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);` as well. This line messes up the preview for the share sheet.

Comment: How did you make uri from a R.id.image . Please add that as well if you could.

Comment: Can you share the final solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This Android [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-direct-share?index=..%2F..index#8) goes through the preview setup which worked for me.

Comment: even within Android themselves got contradict documentations (codelab vs official doc).. interesting..

Answer (score 0):

Final solution (which was working for me) is:

```
val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri) // `uri` is an Uri of a file you're sharing
        type = "image/png" // or whatever other type you have
        // As mentioned in accepted answer, this line is responsible
        // for adding preview in chooser
        clipData = ClipData.newRawUri(null, uri)
        // Without this line, preview was not shown for me,
        // while sharing file itself was possible
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null))
```